# Eclipse - make it use a environment variable to point to the local maven repo in the sourcepath attribute in .classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven

The Maven plugin for Eclipse is finding relevant source code for one of my project's referenced libraries in my local Maven repository and adding a `sourcepath` attribute to my `.classpath` file.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/core/guava-11.0.1.jar" sourcepath="Users/<my_user>/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.1/guava-11.0.1-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

The problem is that I cannot commit the `.classpath` file because it contains a hardcoded path to my local maven repo. Is there a way to tell Eclipse to output that using a environment variable like M2_HOME? Even if it's not automated, is there any token that I can put in there that will let it resolve the location of the source without the hard-coded path? I tried:

```
sourcepath="$M2_HOME/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.1/guava-11.0.1-sources.jar"
```

but Eclipse could not resolve the location of the source for this library after I made this change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With maven 2 you can set the `M2_REPO` classpath variable in Eclipse and `maven eclipse:eclipse` will use it automatically in your `.classpath` file. Details can be seen here: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-configure-m2_repo-variable-in-eclipse-ide/

We've not yet migrated to maven 3 so I am not certain, but I imagine the variable needs to be named `M3_REPO` for maven 3.

Comment: Hmm, but how will that work if I'm relying on Eclipse to build my project? Will I still be able to browse the source of my referenced Jar files from within Eclipse?

Comment: Also, it looks like I already have the variable in my Classpath Variables: `M2_REPO - /Users/bradley/.m2/repository` but the Maven plugin for Eclipse is not using when updating the .classpath file.

Comment: Yes you should be able to browse the source of referenced jar files from within Eclipse.

Now that I check my .classpath files I can see that maven doesn't always use the M2_REPO variable (for me it is the javadoc locations).

As an aside, we don't check in our .classpath and .project files - every developer simply executes `mvn install eclipse:eclipse` the first time they check out the project, then it is all set up for their system (whether it is linux, windows etc).

Comment: Others have had the same problem as you and their ultimate solution was also not to check in the .classpath and .project files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500745/wrestling-with-eclipse-modified-classpath-in-a-mixed-windows-mac-team-environme

Comment: Thanks. We're still using Ant for our builds of this particular project so we're still kind of dependent on Eclipse to manage the project's dependencies at least when compiling within Eclipse. It just so happens that the Guava libraries were in my local Maven repo which is why m2e was finding their source. We'll have to consider making a wholesale switch to Maven and using `mvn install eclipse:eclipse`.

Comment: ... would be nice if m2e had an easy way to say: "update .classpath using M2_REPO classpath variable"

Answer (score 0):

You're right that committing the .classpath or .project files is not a good idea.
However, in the same way that m2e added that value, as would the plugin for other users.  Maven will download the files required on the PC of another user if required (i.e. not in their local repo), and give the correct sourcepath in the `.classpath` file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I believe I'm already using m2e which is how Eclipse knew to add this sourcepath to my local maven repo in the first place. Right? I didn't include that sourcepath attribute myself, it was added when I opened a class in the JAR files. Is there something else that would have done that?

Answer (score 0):

I would add "guava-11.0.1.jar" to a maven repository and then add it as a dependency in my pom.xml. By doing this you won't have "classpathentry" tags in your .classpath file.

After that I would turn on source downloading via the m2eclipse plugin (Window->Maven and check "Download Artifact Sources"). Using sources this way does not add any .classpath file entries.